# MongoDB 3.6.4 "throw err" not recognized, URL cannot be parsed

Tags: mongodb, socket.io, throw

everyone. I'm doing a MongoDB course that was arranged for MongoDB 2.x and I'm getting a problem that hasn't been addressed in the Q&A. The course has more-or-less been abandoned, so neither the instructor nor many students have been active on it.

I'm trying to build a very super-simple Socket.io chat app that uses Mongo. So far, I only have a server.js file and a node_modules folder, and that's basically it. My server.js file goes as follows:

```
  1 const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  2 const client = require('socket.io').listen(3000).sockets;
  3 
  4 mongo.connect( /* 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat',*/ { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
  5     if(err) {
  6         throw err;
  7     }
  8     console.log("The server has started and MongoDB is currently connected.");
  9     client.on('connection', (socket) => {
 10         //
 11     });
 12 });
```

On Line 4, I'd tried it with "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat" uncommented and left in, and without the "useNewUrlParser" portion, since in the course, it's originally presented as:

```
mongo.connect( 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', (err, db) => { //etc. etc.
```

Neither attempt has worked. The error message I'm getting is:

```
/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/server.js:6
        throw err;
        ^

Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed
    at module.exports (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:17:21)
    at deprecated (internal/util.js:53:15)
    at connect (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:980:3)
    at connectOp (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:323:3)
    at executeOperation (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:314:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:536:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ktaherig/Videos/Dev/Traversy Media/MongoDB Projects/SocketChat/server.js:4:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: mongoose version?

Comment: 4.3.: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect

Comment: 5.0: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: 3.8: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect

Comment: In the course, we didn't go over Mongoose. We only used MongoDB.

Comment: @KouroshTeaheri-Golvarzi Try to use with mongoose instead mongodb